# How to get the differences of two set in R?

Tags: r

Suppose:

```
x <- c(2,-5)
y <- c(1,2,3)
```

How can I get :

```
z = c(2-1, 2-2, 2-3, -5-1, -5-2, -5-3) = c(1, 0, -1, -6, -7, -8)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `rep` as follows:

```
rep(x, each = length(y)) - y
# [1]  1  0 -1 -6 -7 -8
```

Answer (score 12):

Using `outer`:

```
> as.vector(outer(x, y, '-'))
# [1]  1 -6  0 -7 -1 -8
```

And if you want the other way:

```
> as.vector(t(outer(x, y, '-')))
# [1]  1  0 -1 -6 -7 -8
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding answer for sake of adding alternative..

```
> x
[1]  2 -5
> y
[1] 1 2 3
> rowSums(expand.grid(-y,x))
[1]  1  0 -1 -6 -7 -8
```

Answer (score 4):

In 2 steps (less elegant than @Ananda solution), using `expand.grid`

```
 d <- expand.grid(x,y)
 transform(d,difference = d$Var1 -d$Var2)
  Var1 Var2 difference
1    2    1          1
2   -5    1         -6
3    2    2          0
4   -5    2         -7
5    2    3         -1
6   -5    3         -8
```

But I think mine is more readable :) ( you know you substract what from what )